# Error writing to parquet file using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on windows 10. I installed spark, and the goal is to use pyspark. I have made the following steps:

1. I have installed Python 3.7 with anaconda -- Python was added to `C:\Python37`
2. I download wintils from [this link](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe) -- winutils is added to `C:\winutils\bin`
3. I downloaded [spark](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe) -- spark was extracted is: `C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7`
4. I downloaded Java 8 from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)

under system variables, I set following variables:

1. `HADOOP_HOME` : `C:\winutils`
2. `SPARK_HOME`: `C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7`
3. `JAVA_HOME`: `C:\PROGRA~1\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.242.08-hotspot`

And finally, under system path, I added:

1. %JAVA_HOME%\bin
2. %SPARK_HOME%\bin
3. %HADOOP_HOME%\bin

In the terminal:

[image]

[image]

So I would like to know why I am getting this warning:

```
unable to load native-hadoop library... And why I couldn't bind on port 4040...
```

Finally, inside Jupyter Notebook, I am getting the following error when trying to write into Parquet file. This image shows a working example, and the following one shows the code with errors:

[image]

And here is DataMaster__3.csv on my disk:

[image]

And the DaterMaster_par2222.parquet:

[image]

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the file in csv format, I have found that the best way to do that is using the following approach

```
LCL_POS.toPandas().to_csv(<path>)
```

There is another way to save it directly without converting to pandas but the issue is it ends up getting split into multiple files (with weird names so I tend to avoid those). If you are happy to split the file up, its much better to write a parquet file in my opinion.

```
LCL_POS.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(<path>)
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: can you please add the full stack-trace so that I can better comment on why this seems to be failing. Also, how much data does this file have and what is the partitioning?

Comment: also, 4040 port usually fails because you have some other process running there? Likely some other terminal which is using that port